# Difference observed between MSVC14.1 and gcc8.3 when a destructor call for an automatic variable amends a function return value

Tags: c++, c++14

Consider the following (to be compiled with C++14)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

// Foo adds an element to a std::vector passed by reference
// on construction in the destructor
struct Foo {
    Foo(std::vector<double>& v) : m_v(v){
    }
    ~Foo(){
        m_v.push_back(1.0);
    }
    std::vector<double>& m_v;
};

std::vector<double> bar(){
    std::vector<double> ret;
    Foo foo(ret);
    return ret;
}

int main(){
    std::cout << bar().size() << "\n";
}
```

In gcc8.3 the output is `1`, which means that `foo`s destructor has an effect on the returned vector.

In MSVC14.1 the output is `0`. You can force the output to be the same as gcc8.3 by replacing the line `Foo foo(ret);` with `{Foo foo(ret);}` (i.e. by forcing the scope).

I don't *think* this is dangling reference undefined behaviour (because `ret` is declared before `foo`) but rather that this could be a bug in MSVC14.1 (and I will create a bug report if so). Does anyone know for sure?

See https://ideone.com/pnxWuJ

Comment: FWIW, MSVC v16.8 (using C++14 standard) gives `1` as the output. So, if it's a bug, it's been fixed already.

Comment: @AdrianMole It's not a bug, both results are conforming. Without elision they all print 0.

Comment: Some more digging, creating a "console app" in MSVC. The release x64 build (accepting the default optimisations) outputs 1, the debug x64 build outputs 0.

Comment: Yeah, elision is typically turned off when debugging. Not that I know if msvc does that, but it would be a reasonable thing to do.

Comment: Considering the answers, this could perhaps be an issue for clarification in the standard itself? Granted, behavior which isn't explicitly defined (or *undefined*) in the specification is left for implementations to define, which means both behaviors are equally valid. But I still think explicitly specified behavior is better (especially if it could lead to such mixed results as described here).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Actually, the standard does specify this with something like "certain calls may be elided even if they have observable side effects". There's not much that can be done to specify it differently. Requiring no elision would affect performance in many cases, and requiring elision is not possible since implementations can't reasonably do that in all cases.

Comment: Your GCC is made by the scooby gang.

Comment: Do you also have a difference when compiling as C++17?

Comment: @Deduplicator there should not be a significant change with C++17 as the mandatory copy elision only apply to RVO, not NRVO.

Answer (score 21):

I think the relevant part of the C++20 standard is [stmt.return], which says

> The copy-initialization of the result of the call is sequenced before the destruction of temporaries at the end of the full-expression established by the operand of the return statement, which, in turn, is sequenced before the destruction of local variables (8.7) of the block enclosing the return statement

So the result of the function call (the return value) should be constructed first, then `foo` is destroyed. Since the returned value is constructed before `foo`'s destructor is run, the result should be 0.

The [class.copy.elision] section says

> When certain criteria are met, an implementation is allowed to omit the copy/move construction of a class object, even if the constructor selected for the copy/move operation and/or the destructor for the object have side effects.

So both compilers can be considered correct.

Comment: Fyi this all makes perfect sense when you want to return a copy of a mutex-protected resource.

Answer (score 16):

I think both compiler are right. NRVO is a common and permitted optimization. If that optimization indeed happen, you're gonna see the item inserted in it by the destructor.

If NRVO don't happen, then just like @1201ProgramAlarm said, the expected behavior is to return the empty vector.

To quote the same content as his answer,

> The copy-initialization of the result of the call is sequenced before the destruction of temporaries at the end of the full-expression established by the operand of the return statement, which, in turn, is sequenced before the destruction of local variables (8.7) of the block enclosing the return statement

So whithout copy elision, you end up copying the vector before the destruction resulting in a size of `0`. With copy elision, you're inserting into the same vector you seen in the main function.

TL;DR: Don't rely on behavior that can change when NRVO is applied. These kind of behavior includes observable side effect from calling a constructor or a destructor, just like your example did.

Comment: About the bottom line; easier said than done. Provide the set of idioms the help avoid such behavior.